# python Search for subdirectories

Tags: python, linux, glob, os.walk

I'd like to create a list of all sub-directories that contain "HICU-B" in their name. Only directories not files (some files in the parent directory contain this too).

I'm wondering if there is a way to combine `glob` and `os.walk()` together to accomplish this. Or if there is another way to go about it.

This is the code I have so far:

This gets the files and directories that contain the text I would like.

```
dirstext=glob.glob('/data01/HICU-B*')
```

And this gets the directories.

```
dirs=next(os.walk('/data01'))[1]
```

I can't figure out how to combine them to get just the directories with "HICU-B" in the name and not the files.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append a slash `'/'` to the end of `HICU-B*`:

```
dirstext = glob.glob('/data01/HICU-B*/')
```

This would return only directories with names starting with `HICU-B*` while files will be excluded.

If you need to `walk` through the matching directories to return all their subdirectories and files, you can do:

```
dirs = [list(i) for i in map(os.walk, dirstext)]
```

Comment: That worked great!

One question - is there a way to get just the directory name and not the path using glob?

Right now it's returning '/data01/HICU-B01' and i'd like just HICU-B01 as am example

Comment: You can `cd` into the directory and do: `glob.glob('HICU-B*/')`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without `cd` ? I'm writing this in a script not command line.

Comment: Oh sprite. Then you can use `os.chdir('/data01/')` to do that in your script. Performs the same thing as `cd`

Comment: Can you combine that with `glob`?

Comment: You'll put that in the line before `glob` like so: `os.chdir('/data01/'); glob.glob('HICU-B*/')`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!